# How to mock BatchWrite object in aws-sdk-net DynamoDb

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, aws-sdk-net

I’m trying to write a unit test in c# and I need to mock the response of the method `CreateBatchWrite<T>` using Moq but I can’t instantiate an object of the `BatchWrite<T>` object.
I’m doing this:

```
this.dynamoDbMock
    .Setup(m => m.CreateBatchWrite<SomeType>(It.IsAny<DynamoDBOperationConfig>()))
    .Returns(Mock.Of<BatchWrite<SomeType>>());
```

Any idea of how can I mock this object.
Thank you!